# Start a service through a sound in android?

Tags: android, audio, service

Is their any possibility to start a service throw a sound in android .If it is possible means please explain the steps with explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is. For playing a "sound" you can use `MediaPlayer` it is very easy to use with local files. You just put the sound files in your assets folder and then call play method of MediaPlayer with a reference to the file. Look apis for exact usage of MediaPlayer.

For service portion, make a service and override `onStartService` method. in this method do all the stuff I said above about playing a sound.

Note that if you use Service you should handle concurrency issues yourself like starting a new thread, ensuring only one sound playing at the same time etc.

So you can use an `IntentService` which basically starts a new thread for each incoming intent.

Comment: thanks for your reply dds.But my actual requirement is if the device can hear the particular sound means i want to start the activity or service to perform some operation